# Facebook page design is not working in IE8

Tags: css, facebook

We have designed a face book page.It is working fine in all browser including IE7 but it is not working in IE8.We checked then we got if we run our code outside the face book page it works in IE8 but when we put our code into face book page its not working.Here is the css code what we are using for IE8.

```
 <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.nv_a
{
    width:90px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
        padding-top:8px;    
}

.nvt_a
{
    width:66px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
        padding-top:8px;    
}

.nv_a a
{
    width:90px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:8px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    border-top:solid 1px #999;
    border-left:solid 1px #999;
    border-right:solid 1px #999;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #999;
}

.nv_a a:hover
{
    width:90px;
    height:27px;
    padding-top:8px;
    float:left;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.nvt_a a
{
    width:66px;
    height:27px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:8px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    border-top:solid 1px #999;
    border-left:solid 1px #999;
    border-right:solid 1px #999;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #999;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Please help us to solve the issue.

Comment: what specifically isn't working? "The Page" doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

"Here is the css code what we are using for IE8."

No, you're not.
The [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at top of your snippet excludes IE8. Maybe what you mean to use there is the "lte" (less than **or equal**) operator?

I can't comment as to why it might be working outside of the Facebook page, but as far as what you're showing, it's correct that the code above doesn't apply to IE8.